# Как сделать программу над другими окнами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, pyqt

Я хочу сделать программу, которая будет над другими окнами.

Это как? Например, вы знаете *Flstudio*? На экране появится фрукт, и вы не можете скрыть его. Но как сделать это? 
Я поискал немало, но все-таки не нашел.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803686/how-to-create-a-modal-dialog-in-tkinter

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window | 
                          QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | 
                          QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)   
                          
    window.setGeometry(750, 350, 100, 100)

    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(100, 100, 
                                            QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, 
                                            QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)
    pal = window.palette()
    pal.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Normal, QtGui.QPalette.Window, 
        QtGui.QBrush(pixmap))
    pal.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, 
        QtGui.QBrush(pixmap))
    window.setPalette(pal)

    window.setMask(pixmap.mask())

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Ok.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как можно добавить кнопки? Или же просто связать с tkinter?

Answer (score 1):

Если пользуетесь PyQt, то вам поможет сплэш скрин.

```
splash = QSplashScreen() # объявляем переменную
splash.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) # ставим флаг "поверх всех окон"
splash.setPixmap(QPixmap('my_splash.png')) # задаем картинку
splash.show() # показываем юзеру
```

Не забудьте в последствии поставить `splash.hide()` и `splash.destroy()` в том месте где ваша заставка должна исчезнуть с экрана.
Ну и само собой в самом начале нужно импортировать необходимые библиотеки:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSplashScreen
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
```

Comment: А как можно добавить кнопки? Или же просто связать с tkinter?

Comment: @Master'sTime В сплэш-скрин кнопки не добавить. С tkinter я не знаком.

Comment: Понятно.... А больше вариантов никак?

Comment: @Master'sTime Если с помощью PyQt будете делать, то нужно создавать не сплэш, а QMainWindow и в нем уже добавлять виджеты и кнопки. Либо использовать QMessageBox. Это большая тема, в комментарии или ответе не уместится.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!